# How do I set the ListView height to the height of the contining row in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I can't figure out the syntax to tell the ListView its height is the height of the row that contains the ListView, that is, the ListView's Parent.
This is the xaml in the user control. I have put what I thought would work, but doesn't. I left it there so you would see what I am attempting.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" 
Height="{Binding Path=Height,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid.Row}}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FolderListTemplate}"
SelectionMode="Single"
SelectedIndex="1"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
Margin="3"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
/>
```

Thanks,

Comment: No repro. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKZAW.png

Comment: Besides that `AncestorType=Grid.Row` makes no sense (because Grid.Row is not a type), simply drop the Height assignment. The Grid will automatically resize its child elements by default. Read the online documentation about the Grid class, and especially its RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Will. Your image shows what I had before I added the height property. The row definitions include Row 0 set to Auto and Row 1 set to *. I named the grid then set the Height property to ActualHeight of the element. The problem with that is the listView goes below the visible area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the **RowDefinition** height to **Auto**, here is my xaml:

```
<Grid Background="DimGray">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Background="CornflowerBlue"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" 
                  x:Name="ListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectedIndex="1"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="3"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Background="CornflowerBlue"/>
    </Grid>
```

And the output:
[image]

If you use star notation then the row it is goin to take the available height for the star value you gave, in this case **1*** which is the same as *****.
If I modify to use star value as you:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The output:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank  you for your response. I did not put enough code in my original question. If I had, everyone would have seen the problem was not with my original ListView (which had no height property set), but was with the HeaderedContentControl Which was the first item in the Row. I just set up my row wrong and that created problems. When My list didn't fit right I kept looking at it rather than the bigger picture. When I removed the Headered content control in order to reduce the clutter, my list view fixed itself.  I marked this as the answer because it will be more useful to someone in the future.